# How can i fetch an array element randomly and then put the contents of the element into the clipboard?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Im fairly new to Visual Basic (being doing it for about a year in college) and i was just messing around with arrays and generating random values ( no real purpose just because )

I already have a bit of code:

```
Dim randomNumber As New Random
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(arry(randomNumber.Next(0, arry.Length)))
```

The array im accessing just stores previously generated random strings (the array works fine) but the problem im having is evertime i attempt to get a string from the array its just returning a null value and i really dont understand. Ive tried a few things but it all seems to come to the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: numbers are not strings.  you might add a line to pick a number, so you can see what will be put on the clipboard, then use `Clipboard.SetText(thisNumber.ToStirng)` to convert the numeric to text.

Comment: This happens always or sometimes?

Comment: also use  arry.length - 1, as that is the arrays upper bound.

Comment: I tried a combination of what you all said, i tried first generating a random number then getting a random element from the array but that didnt seem to work either and neither did adding the -1 (although i know this needed i just forgot to add it)